# Vue v-for loop binding attribute

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in vue, I'm stuck trying to bind the value of the "selected" in the options.

In the simplified code below, I get exactly what I want, but only for the first product. It binds correctly with the first computed property:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in 2" :key="index">
      <select>
        <option :selected="product1 === ''">Empty</option>
        <option
          v-for="(product, index) of products"
          :key="index"
          :selected="product1 === product.name"
        >{{product.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // chosen products come from vuex store
  computed: {
    product1() {
      return store.state.product1;
    },
    product2() {
      return store.state.product2;
    },
  }
</script>
```

But then how can I change this to be automatic in the v-for loop, probably using the index?

What I need is actually a loop that will render this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option :selected="product1 === ''">Empty</option>
      <option
        v-for="(product, index) of products"
        :key="index"
        :selected="product1 === product.name"
        >{{product.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option :selected="product2 === ''">Empty</option>
      <option
        v-for="(product, index) of products"
        :key="index"
        :selected="product2 === product.name"
        >{{product.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've tried using something like:

```
:selected="`product${index}` === product.name"
```

but that gives a string, not the computed property value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass parameter to your computed property:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in 2" :key="index">
      <select>
        <option :selected="getProduct(index) === ''">Empty</option>
        <option
          v-for="(product, index) of products"
          :key="index"
          :selected="getProduct(index) === product.name"
        >{{product.name}}</option>

<script>
  // chosen products come from vuex store
  computed: {
    getProduct() {
      return index=>
           store.state['product'+index];
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This was what I needed to get it working. I also realised I had the "index" twice, in nested v-for loops, which was causing a problem as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the selected products in an array and then access it by index:

```
computed: {
  selectedProducts () {
    return [store.state.product1, store.state.product2];
  }
}
```

And then you can do `:selected="selectedProducts[index] === product.name"`.